# How to declare a variable type depending on a ternary expression?

Tags: swift, enums, variable-declaration, ternary

I have this enum :

```
enum WeatherMapDisplayType {
    case temperature
    case wind
}
```

Can I declare a variable like this ?

```
let markerView: mode == .temperature ? WeatherMapItemTemp : WeatherMapItemWind = UIView.fromNib()
```

Knowing that `mode` is of type `WeatherMapDisplayType`

How can I handle this scenario in an elegant way ?

**EDIT:**

I want to be able to do something like this :

```
let markerView: WeatherMapItem = UIView.fromNib()
markerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 30)
markerView.setupWeatherInformations(mode: self.currentDisplayMode, forecast: forecasts)
marker.iconView = markerView
```

Previously I only had `WeatherMapItem` type.

Then I have been asked to add an other weather map item, that is why I have the `WeatherMapItemTemp` and  `WeatherMapItemWind` now (also corresponding to my enum display type).

---

```
func setupWeatherInformations(forecast: Forecast.HourlyForecast)
```

This is a method in my custom classes in order to configure the outlets.

But I don't have access to this method if I init my custom view from frame, because it's of UIView type.

Comment: Most elegant way here most likely would be using [enums with associated values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html). *markerView with proper type as associated value*.

Comment: What's `WeatherMapItemTemp`? Or `WeatherMapItemWind`?

Comment: It's my custom UIView classes. Can you write an answer with example so that I mark it as answered ?

Comment: @Balanced Answer updated please check

Comment: @Balanced yes you will need to load from nib answer updated please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a common protocol to these views:

```
protocol WeatherMapItem where Self: UIView {
    func setupWeatherInformations()
}

class WeatherMapItemTemp: UIView, WeatherMapItem {
    func setupWeatherInformations() {
        // setup
    }
}

class WeatherMapItemWind: UIView, WeatherMapItem {
    func setupWeatherInformations() {
        // setup
    }
}
```

Add a computed variable to the enum:

```
enum WeatherMapDisplayType {
    case temperature
    case wind

    var view: (UIView & WeatherMapItem)? {
        var nibName: String? = nil
        switch self {
        case .temperature:
            nibName = "WeatherMapItemTemp"
        case .wind:
            nibName = "WeatherMapItemWind"
        }
        if let nibName = nibName, let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: nil), views.count > 0 {
            return views[0] as? UIView & WeatherMapItem
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now you can generate a view like so:

```
// assuming mode is the variable of type WeatherMapDisplayType
let view = mode.view
view?.setupWeatherInformations()
return view
```

Comment: Didn't know about the computed variable. It's powerful. Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to set data in that single ternary statement then declare one function in your custom view class.
Something like following

```
class WeatherMapItemTemp: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    public func setForecast(forecastData: Forecast) -> WeatherMapItemTemp {
        let view = WeatherMapItemTemp.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

        //Set your appropriate value to your view objects
        return view
    }
}
```

Use this as following

```
let markerView = mode == .temperature ? (WeatherMapItemTemp().setForecast(forecastData: YOUR_FORECAST_OBJ)) : (WeatherMapItemWind().setForecast(forecastData: YOUR_FORECAST_OBJ))
```

**Update 2**

Yes you will need to load that from a nib

Update setForecast as following.

```
class func setForecast(forecastData: Forecast) -> WeatherMapItemTemp {
        let view = UINib(nibName: "WeatherMapItemTemp", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! WeatherMapItemTemp

        //Do your further stuff here
        return view
    }
```

Comment: Yes, my custom classes are like that. Check my edited question.

Comment: I am testing it. There won't be an issue loading my XIB file (and outlets) here ?

Comment: As expected, I have the issue with my outlets. I need to loadFromNib no?

Comment: Thank you for your help, the accepted answer is "more elegant". But you helped me well in my thoughts too. Sincerely.